# Como não inicializar o postgresql com o ubuntu?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

Quando executo o comando

```
sudo service postgresql status
```

aparece a seguinte informação:

```
9.3/main (port 5432): online
```

Como eu faço para que o PostgreSQL pare de inicializar junto com o SO (Ubuntu 14 LTS)?

Comment: Tente o seguinte: sudo service postgresql disable